504 gateway timeout error in angular application when backend server is online
I am facing one strange issue since many days in angular website deployed on production.
few random users are facing 504 gateway timeout error and website keep loading and continuously making login request API. When I have checked backend server logs I have not found any logs for such error and backend server is online and up from many days.
After some R&D, I have found below possible cases in which 504 gateway timeout occurs without hitting the backend server or even if backend server is online.

service workers also can give 504 gateway timeout error without contacting the server. I have tried to reproduce this error but not able to reproduce. if anyone can help me to reproduce this error it would be great help.
cloudflare services also give 504 error without hitting the backend server.
sometimes ad blocker like extension also cause 504 gateway timeout error.

what could be possible cases for 504 gateway timeout error with online backend server?

Here is a possible explanation: maybe you have a load-balancer layer in the arch pointing to one of the backend servers that is down or is temporarily down due to some reason for some short amount of time. So most of the requests don't face any error but just the ones that gets redirected to that server.
